# Why might people mistake a nuclear warhead explosion for Lucifer rising?

Tags: religion, nuclear-weapons

So, the cult of Uranius in Kansas City have [just detonated a 50 megaton nuclear warhead](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/116586/what-would-happen-if-a-nuclear-warhead-with-a-yield-of-50-megatons-exploded-in-a), and the entirety of KC is now a deep, deep radioactive crater. A few people saw the bomb explode from about 40 miles away, and they started talking about it to others. The people who saw it all go down say that it was Lucifer, rising from a century-long slumber underground. This is integral to my stories plot, as the whole midwestern population goes crazy thinking that the end of days is near. My question is, why might the post-apocalyptic people think that a nuclear bomb explosion signals the end of days?

Comment: 20 miles away from a 50 megaton bomb would simply turn you to hash... you have been shown were to find this info, and still don't bother do some searching before posting...

Comment: @L.Dutch: Ok, their 40 miles away

Comment: "One participant in the test saw a bright flash through dark goggles and felt the effects of a thermal pulse even at a distance of 270 kilometres (170 mi). The heat from the explosion could have caused third-degree burns 100 km (62 mi) away from ground zero."

Comment: [Lucifer already rises every day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus#Early_studies)

Comment: L.Dutch: Ok, ok, 180 miles away

Comment: Because... someone might think the 7 Years of Tribulation has started earlier than expected and that the nuke might be demons coming to earth?

Comment: Please wait for 24 hours before accepting an answer, since many users don't get on until later and you may be missing out on more information or better answers. (A guideline for the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People throughout history have thought all sorts of things signaled the end of days - eclipses, earthquakes, fires, floods, you name it. A blinding light and a giant fireball on the horizon that obliterates a city and can't be explained doesn't seem too far-fetched as a harbinger of doom.

Comment: Yes, and I’m sorry I forgot to add this in my question, but these people mostly know about the nuclear war that happened before. They know that these weapons caused the apocalypse, and that they were made by mankind